# AOSP custom build gives "Unfortunately, the process com.android.phone has stopped" in startup

Tags: android, android-source

I have an Android Open Source Project custom build for Maguro (Android version 4.0.4).
Somehow it gives an error "Unfortunately, the process com.android.phone has stopped" during startup with some operators, but not all of them.

Anyone else having the same problem and any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ROM probably doesn't support the particular operator. Every custom ROM has to be properly tested against all carriers, phone models etc on which it is expected to work on. But due to the absence of a strict and disciplined organization, testing tends to take a backseat in open source development.

There is a some bug in the rom which is causing it to crash. "com.android.phone" is one of the core processes essential to the phones operation and if this is crashing then there is nothing you can do about it. It is a problem that the developers have to fix.

You can submit a bug report with your device and carrier details to the developers and maybe they will look into it and fix it in the next release.